# Run Android JVM (not instrumented) unit tests in App Center

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center

I'm building my Android ap with Microsoft App Center.

Is there any way to run JUnit JVM unit tests in App Center?
At the moment App Center is running only the Android instrumented tests, this is, the tests that run on one emulator or real device (located in `androidTest` folder)
What I want to do is to run the tests that are pure Java/Kotlin and do not depend in the Android framework to work, the ones that run just on the JVM (located in `test` folder).

All I've found regarding tests in App Center is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/build-test-integration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I contacted App Center and this is not supported yet. I created a feature request for this.